# Cell text overlapping on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

When I scroll my tableview, the text gets all mashed up from the cells below. It's probably cause I recreate the UILabels every time cellForRow gets loaded, but I wouldn't know how to fix it:

```Objective-c
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSDictionary *currentRowDictionary = nil;
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        currentRowDictionary = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        currentRowDictionary = [[self tableData] objectAtIndex:row];

    NSString *voornaam = [currentRowDictionary objectForKey:@"voornaam"];
    NSString *achternaam = [currentRowDictionary objectForKey:@"achternaam"];
    NSString *tussenvoegsel = [currentRowDictionary objectForKey:@"tussenvoegsel"];

    voornaamLbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 40)] autorelease];
    voornaamLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:19];
    voornaamLbl.text = voornaam;
    voornaamLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [voornaamLbl sizeToFit];

    tussenvoegselLbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(voornaamLbl.frame.size.width + 10, 10, 300, 40)] autorelease];
    tussenvoegselLbl.text = tussenvoegsel;
    tussenvoegselLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [tussenvoegselLbl sizeToFit];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:voornaamLbl];
    if ([tussenvoegsel length] != 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tussenvoegselLbl];
        achternaamLbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(voornaamLbl.frame.size.width +
                                                                tussenvoegselLbl.frame.size.width + 15, 10, 300, 40)] autorelease];

    } else {
        achternaamLbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(voornaamLbl.frame.size.width + 10, 10, 300, 40)] autorelease];
    }

    achternaamLbl.text = achternaam;
    achternaamLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [achternaamLbl sizeToFit];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:achternaamLbl];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You alloc and init new labels for everytime a cell is used. Cells are reused during scroll so your multiplying labels each time.

The best way is to create a seperate UITableViewCell subclass that creates the label on load, then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you use your new cell subclass and set the labels text

The end of this tutorial can help with cell subclasses http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1